# xamarin ios push notifications with firebase cloud messaging

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, new Notificationhandler(), true);

```
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        
      
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
       
       
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);

    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);
    }
    // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
    // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
        // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
        // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Do your magic to handle the notification data
        System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }
```

FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize is giving error every time
can nay body help me thanks in advance

Comment: "giving error every time" - what is the error?  Why would you not include this very pertinent information in your post?

Comment: Hello Arvind & welcome on Stackoverflow. 
Please, do a step back and read your question as somebody that is totally unaware of your work. 
Always ask yourself if you did the best, to help the reader understand how he/she can give you a solution. 
I think that this time you put very low effort into exposing your problem: pasting some code and expecting help from other developers, by reading your mind... is a bit too much, even for tech people. 
Please, check this article: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 Cheers